# Jquery display content before using setInterval

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var callAjax = function() {
        $.getJSON('my_data.json', function(jd) {
            $("#main").html("<p> Temperature: " + jd.Temperature + "</p>");
            $("#main").append("<p>  Temperature: " + jd.Temperature2 + "</p>");
            $("#main").append("<p> Humidity: " + jd.Humidity + "</p>");
        });
    }
    setInterval(callAjax, 2000);
});
```

The code i displayed above is used to call ajax itself every 2 seconds and update values from json file. The problem is that I want to display right at the beginning  these paragrpahs with values that are currently in the json file then update them every two second just like in the code. 
Now when i run this html file it waits first for two second then call ajax. Is there any way to display values immediatly and then update them automatically by calling function call callAjax every two seconds?

Comment: Just call the 'callAjax' function right after the page loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... You've defined a function:

```
var callAjax = function() {
  //...
};
```

And you've set it to run at intervals:

```
setInterval(callAjax, 2000);
```

And now you simply want to execute it once right away?  Well, executing a function is pretty simple:

```
callAjax();
```

So putting them together seems simple enough:

```
var callAjax = function() {
  //...
};

setInterval(callAjax, 2000);
callAjax();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the solution is this

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var callAjax = function() {
            $.getJSON('my_data.json', function(jd) {
                $("#main").html("<p> Temperature: " + jd.Temperature + "</p>");
                $("#main").append("<p>  Temperature: " + jd.Temperature2 + "</p>");
                $("#main").append("<p> Humidity: " + jd.Humidity + "</p>");
            });
            }
      callAjax();
      setInterval(callAjax, 2000);      
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When the page is requested read the file and fill the contents so it will show immediately when the page loads.
In PHP it would look something like this.

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('mydata.json'));
?>
<div id="main">
    <p>Temperature: <?= $data.temperature ?></p>
    <p>Temperature: <?= $data.Temperature2 ?></p>
    <p> Humidity: <?= jd.Humidity ?></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
var callAjax = (function () { ... }());
```

Notice the parenthesis at them, it's a self calling function.

Answer (score 0):

Call your callAjax function before using the setInterval:

```
callAjax();
setInterval(callAjax, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = true;
     function callAjax(){
        i = false;
        $.getJSON('my_data.json', function(jd) {
            $("#main").html("<p> Temperature: " + jd.Temperature + "</p>");
            $("#main").append("<p>  Temperature: " + jd.Temperature2 + "</p>");
            $("#main").append("<p> Humidity: " + jd.Humidity + "</p>");
        });
        }
     }
var $callajax = i == true ? callAjax() : setInterval(function(){ callAjax() },2000);
```